# Json to Nested Models in Backbone.js

Tags: json, backbone.js

Hello I have the following JSON provided from a server. With this I want to create a model with a nested model.

```
//json
{
    "2": {
        "sheet_id": 2,
        "distribution_id": 4,
        "areas": {
            "1": {
                "area_id": "1",
                "image_id": "164"
            },
            "2": {
                "area_id": "2",
                "image_id": "164"
            }
        }
    },
    "3": {
        "sheet_id": 3,
        "distribution_id": 4,
        "areas": {
            "1": {
                "area_id": "1",
                "image_id": "165"
            },
            "2": {
                "area_id": "2",
                "image_id": "164"
            }
        }
    },
}
```

I want these to be converted to two nested backbone models with the following structure:

**Structure**

```
Project has many Sheets and Sheet has many Areas
```

Comment: it's hardly possible to recognize what the structure you are expecting is and what you are exactly asking.

Answer (score 2):

The answer largely depends on how often this sort of pattern will repeat itself.

There is fantastic backbone classes that replace or augment the `Model` class which lets you do what you're looking for:

- [Backbone Deep Model](https://github.com/kahwee/backbone-deep-model)
- [Backbone Nested Models](https://github.com/blittle/backbone-nested-models)
- [Backbone Documentmodel](https://github.com/icereval/backbone-documentmodel)

Of course you can also roll a 1-off solution in `parse:` method to manually init models or collections of the nested resources.

Comment: Thanks @Smazurov. And what do you recommend me? deep model or nested models? Did you use it with multiple nested classes?

Comment: I would probably go with Deep Model personally, but as suish mentioned in his comment, its entirely dependent on your project. The question does not have enough information to make an informed recommendation.

Comment: And what about collections? I was reading this post and may be is a native solution http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-collection/

Comment: Backbone collections are basically a way to do things with a list of models.  You could represent each `sheet` in a `Sheets` collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this library,

[Backbone Relational](http://backbonerelational.org)

You can create structure of models as you have mentioned using backbone relational.